# Enviro Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitignore

Used ENV in my text editor when configuring a rails app for gmail and mail chimp. I thought I did it properly, navigating to the secrets.yml file within the config app directory.

When I pushed to github, everything showed up. My passwords and mail chip API were all there...how did I screw this up and not properly use the Enviro Variables?? I reverted the public repository so that the info would no longer be there, but I'd like to figure this out. If anybody could ALSO answer how I would add the secrets.yml file to the .gitignore directory, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

go to

```
.gitignore
```

add the file name like

```
/locales/secrets.yml
```

and if you have an env file add

```
.env
```

There are also gems you can use like dotenv-rails